# Location of EDITBIN in Microsoft-hosted agents

Tags: azure-devops, build-agent

How do I find the location of the [EDITBIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/editbin-reference) on a Microsoft-hosted agent? I'm trying to use it to set [SWAPRUN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/swaprun) for the output DLLs of a C# project.

For a local build, I use `$(DevEnvDir)\..\..\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\Hostx86\x86\editbin`. However, on the Microsoft-hosted agent, `DevEnvDir` is not defined, nor do I know if the rest of the path would work?

A related bonus question is where can I find in general the file structure for a Microsoft-hosted agent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `editbin.exe` exist in Hosted VS2017 agent in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\SDK\ScopeCppSDK\VC\bin\editbin.exe
```

And to get the folder structure you can use a powershell script, such as:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017"
Get-childItem | tree
```

And if you want to check the structure of a root directory like `C:\`, it will cost a lot of time.

Comment: In 2019, there may be an additional ``\vc15\`` before the `VC`.

Answer (score 0):

For automated reasons one might select the correct variant of editbin automatically. I came up with the following PS script:

```
# define search parameters
$hostsys = "\hostx64"
$target = "\x86"
$basepath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\"

# determine paths to the editbin executable and select the preferred one
$findings = Get-childItem -Path $basepath -Recurse -Include "editbin.exe"
$editbinexe = ""

Write-Host "`nEditbin candidates:"
foreach ($item in $findings) {
    [string]$directory = $item.DirectoryName.ToLower()
    Write-Host "$directory"
    
    if ($directory.Contains($hostsys) -and $directory.Contains($target))
    {
        $editbinexe = $item.FullName
    }
}

if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($editbinexe))
{
    Write-Host "`nEditbin was not found`n"
    exit -120
}

# execute the found executable

Write-Host "`nUsing editbin ""$editbinexe""`n"
Set-Location .\<the path to executable>
& $editbinexe /LARGEADDRESSAWARE "<the executable>"
```